# Query Multiple IDs in 1 table row to another table in 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in MySQL
**table1**
ID|name|group_1|group_2|group_3

**Table2** 
ID|group_name|Group_location

I want to get table 1 ID and show all the data and not tableIDs.
I'm trying to use a join like so

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.group_1, table1.group_2, table1.group_3
FROM tabl1 JOIN table2 on table1.group_1 = table2.ID  AND
table1.group_2 = table2.ID   AND table1.group_3 = table2.ID
WHERE table1.ID IN (868) 
ORDER BY FIELD(table1.ID,868);
```

It's only returning the IDs in the result but I want it to return the table2 group_name
[image]

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT t1.name, t21.group_1, t22.group_2, t23.group_3
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t21
     ON t1.group_1 = t21.ID LEFT JOIN
     table2 t21
     ON t1.group_2 = t22.ID LEFT JOIN
     table2 t21
     ON t1.group_3 = t23.ID 
WHERE t1.ID IN (868) 
ORDER BY FIELD(t1.ID, 868);
```

This uses `LEFT JOIN` in case any of the reference columns are `NULL`.

Comment: What does `WHERE t1.ID IN (868) 
ORDER BY FIELD(t1.ID, 868)` do?

Comment: @Strawberry . . . That is in the OP's original query.  I would suggest that you put this comment on the question and not the answer.  (But if I had to guess, the values are being munged into the query and this ensures that the ordering of the result set matches the desired ordering.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
 SELECT t1.name
      , t21.group_name
      , t22.group_name
      , t23.group_name 
   FROM table1 t1 
   LEFT 
   JOIN table2 t21 
     ON t1.group_1 = t21.ID 
   LEFT 
   JOIN table2 t21 
     ON t1.group_2 = t22.ID 
   LEFT 
   JOIN table2 t21 
     ON t1.group_3 = t23.ID 
  WHERE t1.ID IN (868) 
  ORDER 
     BY FIELD(t1.ID, 868);
```